# uploading video to youtube livestream event python

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming

I am trying to make an application in python that allows me to live stream my camera video to YouTube.
So far with google developer's documentation's help I have successfully inserted, live streamed and bind it to broadcast.

I currently believe that the live stream is just an event and I will have to upload video separately (I don't know if I am right or wrong about this).
If you can explain to me how to add video in it (please try to keep it free as its for my university project, I don't know if live streaming through any service have any charges or not).
I have read somewhere about ffmpeg but can't figure out how to use it.
I am working on python 3.4, O.S is windows 10.

this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import argparse
import http.client as httplib
import httplib2
import os
import random
import time
import re
import ffmpeg
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import sys
import  urllib.error
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the {{ Google Cloud Console }} at
# {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_id.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
ACTIONS = ('get', 'list', 'set')
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0
To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:
   %s
with information from the {{ Cloud Console }}
{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}
For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

def get_authenticated_service_VIDEO():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

# Create a liveBroadcast resource and set its title, scheduled start time,
# scheduled end time, and privacy status.
def insert_broadcast(youtube, options):
  insert_broadcast_response = youtube.liveBroadcasts().insert(
    part="snippet,status",
    body=dict(
      snippet=dict(
        title=options.broadcast_title,
        scheduledStartTime=options.start_time,
        scheduledEndTime=options.end_time
      ),
      status=dict(
        privacyStatus=options.privacy_status
      )
    )
  ).execute()

  snippet = insert_broadcast_response["snippet"]


  print("Broadcast '%s' with title '%s' was published at '%s'." % (
    insert_broadcast_response["id"], snippet["title"], snippet["publishedAt"]))
  return insert_broadcast_response["id"]

# Create a liveStream resource and set its title, format, and ingestion type.
# This resource describes the content that you are transmitting to YouTube.
def insert_stream(youtube, options):
  insert_stream_response = youtube.liveStreams().insert(
    part="snippet,cdn",
    body=dict(
      snippet=dict(
        title=options.stream_title
      ),
      cdn=dict(
        format="1080p",
        ingestionType="rtmp"
      )
    )
  ).execute()

  snippet = insert_stream_response["snippet"]

  print("Stream '%s' with title '%s' was inserted." % (
    insert_stream_response["id"], snippet["title"]))
  return insert_stream_response["id"]

# Bind the broadcast to the video stream. By doing so, you link the video that
# you will transmit to YouTube to the broadcast that the video is for.
def bind_broadcast(youtube, broadcast_id, stream_id):

  bind_broadcast_response = youtube.liveBroadcasts().bind(
    part="id,contentDetails",
    id=broadcast_id,
    streamId=stream_id
  ).execute()

  print("Broadcast '%s' was bound to stream '%s'." % (
    bind_broadcast_response["id"],
    bind_broadcast_response["contentDetails"]["boundStreamId"]))

  # VBR = "2500k"  # Bitrate de la vidéo en sortie
  # FPS = "30"  # FPS de la vidéo en sortie
  # QUAL = "medium"  # Preset de qualité FFMPEG
  # YOUTUBE_URL = "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"  # URL de base RTMP youtube
  #
  # SOURCE = '/dev/video0'  # Source UDP (voir les annonces SAP)
  # KEY = "...."  # Clé à récupérer sur l'event youtube
  #
  # ffmpeg
  #     .input()
  # -i "$SOURCE" - deinterlace ^
  # -vcodec libx264 - pix_fmt yuv420p - preset $QUAL - r $FPS - g $(($FPS * 2)) - b: v $VBR ^
  # -acodec libmp3lame - ar 44100 - threads 6 - qscale3 - b: a 712000 - bufsize 512 k ^
  # -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
  # vid = youtube.insert(
  #   part="id,contentDetails",
  #   id=broadcast_id,
  #   streamId=stream_id
  # ).execute()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--broadcast-title", help="Broadcast title",
    default="Teing BD")
  argparser.add_argument("--privacy-status", help="Broadcast privacy status",
    default="public")
  argparser.add_argument("--start-time", help="Scheduled start time",
    default='2018-11-27T13:33:00.000Z')
  argparser.add_argument("--end-time", help="Scheduled end time",
    default='2018-11-27T13:50:00.000Z')
  argparser.add_argument("--stream-title", help="Stream title",
    default="Project ")
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  try:
    broadcast_id = insert_broadcast(youtube, args)
    stream_id = insert_stream(youtube, args)
    bind_broadcast(youtube, broadcast_id, stream_id)
  except (HttpError, e):
    print("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

giving the output:

[image: Screencap of problem]

Comment: See [ask]. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried along with an [mcve] that shows the specific problem, and show us what results you get.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience i have edited the question and added my code as well as output picture link that how my stream is looking please let me know if you needed any other info. Thank you Sir.

Comment: This is a bit broad. It's hard to know what the specific question is. There are examples here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/python that may help.